# Why does my lm() function return an "undefined columns selected" error?

Tags: r, undefined

I am trying to perform a linear regression on a data set using the lm() function. The dataset is a csv file with 50 columns and 137 rows. My code was returning several errors such as invalid file type, variable lengths differ, and undefined columns selected.

I first tried to run

```
model <- lm(dataset[,50] ~ (dataset[137,]), data = dataset)
```

and got the error

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = dataset[, 50] ~ list((dataset[137,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'list((dataset[137, ]))'
```

Several threads said to try as.matrix or unlist() for the dataset[137,] argument.

Running

```
model <- lm(dataset[,50] ~ unlist(dataset[137,]), data = dataset)
```

yielded

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = dataset[, 50] ~ unlist(dataset[137,  :
> variable lengths differ (found for 'unlist(dataset[137, ])')

And

```
model <- lm(dataset[50,] ~ as.matrix(dataset[,137]), data = dataset)
```

gave me the error

> Error in `[.data.frame`(dataset, , 137) : undefined columns selected

Comment: `dataset[137,]` is row 137, do you want column 137? The last error means that there is no column 137, `ncol(dataset)` is smaller than 137.

Comment: why mess with square brackets in this context ? what could be easier/more convenient than using the column's name ?  without names you lose the ability to do a simple predict() etc. Now I might understand if you have particularly awkward column names, and want to learn ways to rename your columns; but that would be quite a different post...